# Jquery mobile - How to collapse all except one that i click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery mobile on my mobile site to make my collapsible div's, I need to expand that one I click and collapse others. Is it possible ? Thank you very much. [Site](http://testing3.ats-global.com/cz/cs/8_about-ats.html)

jQuery:

```
   ('#featured h3 a').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio .ui-collapsible-content').hide();
    $('#cusomer_references .ui-collapsible-content').hide();
    $('#featured .ui-collapsible-content').hide();
   });
   ('#featured_copy h3 a').click(function(){
    $('#our_business .ui-collapsible-content').hide();
    $('#cusomer_references .ui-collapsible-content').hide();
    $('#featured .ui-collapsible-content').hide()   
   });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="featured" data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Featured</h3>                                                                        
                        <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Inspect</a>
                        <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS CM4D</a><br />
</div>    

<div id="featured_copy" data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Featured</h3>                                                                        
                        <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Inspect</a>
                        <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS CM4D</a><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
 $('#featured h3,#featured_copy h3').click(function(e){
$(this).parent().children().toggle();
  $(this).show();
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8SPj3/4/)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answer. But i need to collapse (my english is bad but I think It means something like hide items inside) other divs except one I pick.

Comment: you dont want toggle?

Comment: No, I need show one tha I pick and hide others, not to have 2 divs open (only one open other closed) if it is possible ?

Comment: Its like that, if you click on the headings it will show, if it is already shown, then it hide

Comment: If `#featured h3` is open and i click on `#feature_copy h3`. I need to display only `featured h3` without content inside and open `#featured_copy h3` with content inside.

Comment: @user3342042 did you check the fiddle in the above comment?

Comment: I found solution myself : `<div data-role="collapsible-set">`